# Silliness: $\exists~X~\text{s.t.}~AX=B \iff B\in R(L_A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices, vector-spaces

So, I am asked to prove that the system of linear equations $AX=B$ has $\color{black}{a~solution}$ if and only if $B\in R(L_A)$. $R$ denotes the "range of" and $L_A$ is left multiplication by $A$. If the question says "a solution" does that mean that I can rely on the fact that it's invertible?

Friedberg's 1989 edition of *Linear Algebra* says the above are equivalent, namely that $\exists~X~\text{s.t.}~AX=B \iff B\in R(L_A)$:

[image]

How am I to "prove" this?

Comment: No. The system $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ has a solution, but the $A$ in question is not invertible.

Comment: $L_A$ is an operator, with a domain, range, and kernel.   $B$ is in that range if and only if  for some input $X$, $L_A(X)=B$.

Comment: The proof seems straight forward. If that system has a solution, then that means there exists an $X$ which, under the action of $A$, is mapped to $B$ under left multiplication.

Comment: Why does that sound circular? What does it mean for $B$ to be outside the range of left multiplication by $A$? What is an example of this?

Comment: There is no gain from using colors like that. In fact, there may be actual loss. For example, the color you picked is so light that I just cannot read it. And there are people with various sight problems which make some colors difficult to see, and so on...

Comment: Yes... I'll change that. Here is my reasoning: If $AX=B$ has a solution then there exists an $n-$tuple which when acted upon by $A$ produces the $m-$tuple $B$. This $m-tuple$ is clearly in the range of $L_A$ because left multiplication by $A$ is defined as $L_A:F^n\rightarrow F^m$ such that $L_A(X)=AX$. This doesn't seem too solid though...

Comment: Forgive me, all people who suffer from tritanopia, deuteranopia, protanopia, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's best if we state the definition of range first.

**Definition:** Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix and consider the linear mapping $L_A:\mathbb{F}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{F}^m$ induced by $A$ as $L_A(\mathbf{x}) = A\mathbf{x}$. We denote the **range** or **image** of $L_A$ as the set of all vectors $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{F}^m$ such that $\mathbf{b}=L_A(\mathbf{x})$ for some $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{F}^n$. We denote the range as 
$$\mathrm{R}(L_A) = \{\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{F}^m\mid \exists \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{F}^n\ L_A(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{b}\}$$
$$$$

Now, if there exists $\mathbf{x}$ such that $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ then by definition of $L_A$ we have $A\mathbf{x} = L_A(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{b}$. This means that $\mathbf{b}$ is a member of the range since there exists some $\mathbf{x}$ such that $L_A(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{b}$.

Conversely, suppose that $\mathbf{b}$ is in the range of $L_A$. By definition of range, there exists some $\mathbf{x}$ such that $L_A(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{b}$. By definition of $L_A$ we have $L_A(\mathbf{x}) = A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ so $\mathbf{x}$ satisfies the system.

Comment: For what reason is it necessary here to show "both ways"? Can you show to me an example where the converse would be false? I understand that $iff$-statements are done this way, but why is it **necessary** here?

Comment: @BarisaBarukh For this particular theorem I don't have an example where the converse is false because it isn't (and we proved it)! In general though the statements $P\implies Q$ and $Q\implies P$ are independent. Proving one direction says _nothing_ about the opposite direction and that's why it's necessary. I think one of the reasons why you think it is unnecessary is because this "theorem" is really a restatement of something using the definition of **range** and definitions are if-and-only-ifs. I could give a one line proof of this statement which hides the two directions if you want.

Comment: You are talking about an $iff$-chain argument, yes?

Comment: Sure, give me your one-liner.

Comment: @BarisaBarukh Essentially yea. There exists $\mathbf{x}$ such that $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ if and only if there exists $\mathbf{x}$ such that $L_A(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{b}$ if and only if $\mathbf{b}\in \mathrm{R}(L_A)$.

Comment: How is it that your answer gets up-voted so quickly?

Comment: Under what condition would this intermediary step ($\exists~X~\text{s.t.}~L_A(X)=B$) need to be changed so that $B\not\in R(L_A)$?

Comment: Are you asking for the negation of the statement? In that case $\mathbf{b}\notin \mathrm{R}(L_A)$ implies that there does _not_ exist an $\mathbf{x}$ such that $L_A(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{b}$.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is of the shape
\begin{eqnarray}
\overset{m}{\boxed{\huge A}}\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\Large n}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}}{},
\end{eqnarray}
and $X$ is of the shape
\begin{eqnarray}
\overset{n}{\boxed{\huge X}}\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\Large 1}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}}{},
\end{eqnarray}
so $AX$ has the shape
\begin{eqnarray}
\overset{m}{\boxed{\huge A}}\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\Large n}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}~\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\Large \times}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}~~\overset{n}{\boxed{\huge X}}\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\Large 1}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}}{} ~\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\Large =}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}}{} ~~\overset{m}{\boxed{\huge AX}}\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{\Large 1}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}}{}.
\end{eqnarray}
$AX$—that is, $B$—is an $m$-tuple for which it is thus a element of the range of $L_A$, for if $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with entries from a field $F$, then we denote by $L_A$ the mapping $L_A:F^n\rightarrow F^m$ defined by $L_A(X)=AX$ (the matrix product of $A$ and $X$) for each column vector $x\in F^n$.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to be satisfying...

Comment: $F^m$ is the set of all $m$-tuples over the field $F$, so is it not plain enough that the statement is so true to not need a proof?

Comment: Do you know the precise definition of **range**?

Comment: @EuYu Is there a flaw in my argument?

Comment: Mine seems more organic, no?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're trying to prove here. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the statement in question. Where is $\mathbf{b}$?

Comment: Is not $B$ clearly $AX$?

Comment: No it's not. The point of this is that $\mathbf{b}$ is the one which is given. From $\mathbf{b}$ you have to find $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: Does not "has a solution" imply that $X$ is already known? I see this as "has a solution" $\implies$ "solution is mapped to an element of $F^m$".

Comment: If you're taking the $X$ to be the one given by the hypothesis, then yes, it is known. In that case then you are proving the forward direction. Your argument essentially boils down to "there exists $X$ such that $L_A(X) = B$" which is exactly the same as the argument I gave. But previously you didn't mention that $X$ has a specified role. And there's always the converse which needs to be proven.

Comment: Why does the converse need to be proven? I get that in certain cases it is required, but perhaps I just don't get the origin of this forward-backward mode of concrete reasoning.

Comment: @EuYu You're not [this guy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBLDRWrb9sc) are you?

Comment: As I mentioned before, there is no dependence between the two directions of an if-and-only-if statement. Statements cannot be taken as true until they are proven. So let me ask in turn, why do you think the proof is unnecessary? And no, I am not him.

Comment: How are you using the word "induced" here?

Comment: I'm using "induced" in the same sense as "given by" or "obtained from" here. There is nothing technical about the word, if you're uncomfortable with it, feel free to change it to "where $L_A$ is the linear map obtained from $A$ by $L_A(\mathbf{x})=A\mathbf{x}$."

Comment: Why do you speak so strongly? Your style of communication is almost brusque.

Comment: Well, mathematics is a very precise language so it never hurts to speak precisely. This is especially true when communicating a proof to someone. Also a bit of occupational hazard I guess.

Comment: No, I mean your use of the word "uncomfortable" seems entirely useless.

Comment: I guess. I thought that maybe you didn't like the use of the word since it also has a mathematical meaning.

Comment: Incorrect, you assume too much.